# Django 1.4.1 not loading admin site (Django Book tutorial)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can't figure out why Django is not loading the admin page. It seems like it isn't even reading the urls.py file that I am editing - because even if I comment out the 'urlpatterns' statement, it still loads the local hello page fine once I run the server.

This is the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^hello/$
^time/$
^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$
The current URL, admin, didn't match any of these.
```

This is my urlpatterns code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mysite.views import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello, ),
    ('^time/$', current_datetime, ),
    (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead, ),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

And this is a snippet os my settings.py file:

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/pavelfage/Desktop/Coding/mysite/Templates',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'mysite.books'
)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Your requested url is, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin", did you try it with the trailing slash, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/"?

Comment: Hi monkut - just tried, same result (no result). I think Django is not even looking at the urls.py and/or settings.py files that I am editing - is there a way to find out where it's looking, or instruct it to look at a particular file as can be done with pythonpath?

Comment: This would not work, else /admin would have show up in the error message

Comment: Can you remove the url keyword, and try?

Comment: Hi karthikr - I tried that, does not seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: What I don't understand is that even if I delete the entire urls.py file, save it blank, and runserver again - the 'hello' page is still showing up. Doesn't this mean that I am looking at the wrong file? How do I figure out which file Django is reading from?

Comment: And one more try. Can you add a string around admin.urls.py? Like this include('admin.urls.py')

Comment: yes, you may have duplicate files, it's common to include the root urls.py in the same directory as your settings.py file and then have a per app urls.py in the app folder.  You may have copied the root one to a registered app folder without realizing it.

Comment: Yes. You are most likely reading off of a duplicate file. Can you look in urls.py along with manage.py?

Comment: Okay - can I check somehow what settings/views/models/urls files Django is looking at on my machine? It is clearly that it's not reading from the file I think it is - but I cannot identify any duplicates...

Comment: You could try running the interactive shell in Django. `python manage.py shell`, `from django.conf import settings`, `print settings.ROOT_URLCONF`.

Comment: Perhaps delete any urls.pyc files too.

Comment: Thanks guys - I deleted the entire project, reinstalled it from scratch, and it is now working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You may try this:

- In your urls.py replace the call include(admin.site.urls) by this: admin.site.urls
- In your setting.py if don't have any TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS property (that was my situation) add this:

  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =    ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",    "django.core.context_processors.debug",    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",    "django.core.context_processors.media",    "django.core.context_processors.static",    "django.core.context_processors.tz",    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")

It seams to be roughly the default property in a normal django 1.4 configuration. Here are the docs talking about it: [djangoproject-doc1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) [djangoproject-doc2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

You may also have to uncomment the strings:

```
# 'django.contrib.messages',
# 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

in your INSTALLED_APPS property of the settings.py but i'm not sure about it.

Sorry about not explaining much better the reasons of those changes but I'm a django-beginner to. I just found your question corresponding to my problem and then a possible awnser.

I hope it may help you.

EDIT: as seen in a comment you may try to remove the url(...) instruction on the line concerning the url of the admin site

ben

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem. Uncommenting `from django.contrib import admin` in urls.py solved the problem.